# How to Set the Background Drawable of a Button Properly Android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the background of a button when the user press it in the emulator everything works fine but on a real device the app crash. 
here is my code:

```
answerOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               answerOne.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_green);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ValidateAnswer(current5,Answers_six[0]);
            }
        });
```

and the error in the log is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nasrf.winners10, PID: 9715
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080060
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1416)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:861)
                      at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
                      at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16423)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatButton.java:83)
                      at com.example.nasrf.winners10.Game.GameActivity$16.onClick(GameActivity.java:426)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4802)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20101)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening due to the difference in the SDK of your emulator and real device.

You can check the sdk first and then set the Background like this -

```
     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
         answerOne.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background_green));
       }
       else if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)         {
      answerOne.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background_green));
     } else{
       answerOne.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.button_background_green));
   }
```